# configuring Jappix Mini

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I just got started to work with Jappix Mini but I can't make it to work properly.
the anonymous example which provided in [it's download page](https://mini.jappix.com/get) works fine but I cant configure it to work with my own server.
how can I configure it to connect to my jabber server at http://example.net:5280/http-bind ??
does it automatically understand that it should connect to port 5280 and furthermore does it use http to connect to server??

Answer (score 0):

Set the global bosh variable, e.g.:

```
HOST_BOSH = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + ':5280/http-bind';
```